# Copying table data while modifying some of the fields - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to copy one table into another table while changing a single field. Suppose that I have table_aaa, and it has about a hundred fields. I want to create table_bbb based on table_aaa, so I do:

```
CREATE TABLE table_bbb 
    (LIKE table_aaa INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES);
```

Then I want to fill table_bbb. If I only wanted a copy of table_aaa, I would have done:

```
INSERT INTO table_bbb SELECT * FROM table_aaa;
```

However, I want to change field_87 (there are field_1..field_100 in these tables). I could update after the insert, like this:

```
UPDATE table_bbb set field_87 = field_87 * 2
```

However, this table is very large, I have many tables that need to undergo the same operation, and the system is down while I'm doing this - so I would like to skip the UPDATE and make this magic happen while INSERTing.

Am I out of luck, or is there any solution I'm missing?

Comment: I don't understand that last bit. How will this reduce the time the system is down? Why is the system down while you're doing this? Why are you copying a table in production? Are the columns really called things like "field_87"?

Comment: I have to stop the system before making the change, otherwise this will lead to data inconsistency. I'm looking for ways for minimizing the time it takes.

Comment: Doing it in a transaction should take care of that.  Are table_aaa and table_bbb supposed to remain the same after the INSERT/UPDATE?  Maybe all you need is a materialized view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this in the `select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_bbb  (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column_1, 
       column_2, 
       column_3 * 2
FROM table_aaa;
```

Comment: That would work of course; however I'll have to actually write all the fields (hundreds of them), and if the tables change I have to update my script.

Comment: @EldadMor: "*hundreds of columns" might indicate a wrong database design to begin with. But this is really the only way if you want to avoid the `update`

Comment: I agree. My question was more theoretical than practical in the sense of amounts of columns. Nevertheless, I do have a few tables that have more than just a few columns, and this solution in its naive form will be very cumbersome. In addition, I have to be aware of any schema updates, which is very error-prone.

Comment: @EldadMor: Doesn't your SQL client support auto-completion so you don't have to type all the columns manually? Plus: you could write a function that will automatically generate the needed statement and execute it using dynamic SQL. You pass it the table names and the expression to be used for a specific column.

Comment: It does, but this is not something suitable for a manual work - this is a part of a database migration operation that is supposed to run fast and be thoroughly tested in advance. Indeed, I ended up writing a function.

Answer (score 0):

Like a_horse_with_no_name said, apparently there's no way around such an insert. However, for a real-world solution where you need to migrate a lot of tables with a lot of columns, the manual solution is not good enough.

I ended up writing a pgplsql stored function that receives a table name and the columns to be changed, and does this operation in an automatic way. I also threw in some table renaming, index renaming and sequence manipulating, because that was my entire goal (per-table). If you run into the same problem and need assistance, let me know.